# Is there a way that i can pass a string uninterpreted in a url?

Tags: url, browser, webserver, zabbix

I have a zabbix server that sends me a mail whenever there is an issue.

It uses a template like this, to generate the mail

```
Issue: {TRIGGER.ISSUE}
Description: "Node: {TRIGGER.NODE}, {TRIGGER.DESCRIPTION}"
```

And the mail would look like:

```
Issue: "memory usage"
Description: "Node: abc.def.com, high memory usage (>90%)"
```

I need to pass this information on to a web server after which appropriate action will be taken. The way I thought is by putting
the url inside that template something like this

```
http://localhost:4567?issue={TRIGGER.ISSUE}&nodename={TRIGGER.NODE}&description={TRIGGER.DESCRIPTION}
```

But this sometimes generates a string that will not be properly encoded into a URI and I often run into Bad URI issues on my browser.

Is there a way that I can pass on the strings such that it goes through as a raw string and does not get interpreted by the browser?

Comment: Do you need to create real http GET request or is it just link in the email?

Comment: I would like to create a real http GET request on clicking that link in the mail.  The intention is to pass on this information to the server so that appropriate action can be taken. Any other suggestion to achieve the same would be useful. I know zabbix can be made to execute a script on a trigger, but due to various reasons, I would still like to accomplish this within the framework of an email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some characters (white space, &, ...) in `{TRIGGER.DESCRIPTION}` or `{TRIGGER.NODE}` macros are your problem. Unfortunately, Zabbix doesn't provide any *urlencode* function in the template. Fortunately, you can write your own alertscript which will solve your problem. Just pick up your favorite language, which support *urlencode* function (or write your own) and use *urlencode* function for any macro, which you use in the URL. Your script must be able to send also email.

Doc:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding
- https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/notifications/media/script